# Passing array of strings as launch arguments in ROS2 python launcher

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

I am not able to set an array of string as a launch argument in a launcher:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    vals = ['A', 'B']
    model_files = LaunchConfiguration('model_files', default=vals)
    
    declare_model_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
      'model_files',
       default_value=vals,
       description='PDDL Model file')

    # Specify the actions
    domain_expert_cmd = Node(
      package='plansys2_domain_expert',
      node_executable='domain_expert_node',
      node_name='domain_expert',
      output='screen',
      parameters=[{'model_files': model_files}])
    
    ld = LaunchDescription()
    ld.add_action(declare_model_file_cmd)
    ld.add_action(domain_expert_cmd)

    return ld
```

In my C++ node:

```
    declare_parameter("model_files", std::vector<std::string>());
```

I receive this message:

```
[domain_expert_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::ParameterTypeException'
[domain_expert_node-1]   what():  expected [string_array] got [string]
```

Does anybody know how to use an array of string as a launcher argument?

Best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341540/passing-array-of-strings-as-launch-arguments-in-ros2-python-launcher/) by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2020-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is happening because launch substitutions like `LaunchConfiguration` always return a string. So, in your example, `vals` is being concatenated into the single string "AB", which is not the array type that your node expects. Perhaps it's more of a workaround, but you can make your Python list a string instead. I.e. `vals = "['A', 'B']"`. The same should work from the command line as well:

```
ros2 launch your.launch.py model_files:="[foo, bar, baz]"
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1